# make codename and index in agreement

Tags: excel, vba

In the project window, codename is displayed before the tab name. So, you see something like "Sheet8 (test)". In the property window, codename is displayed to the right of "(Name)". Index number is not that obvious to see but usually, the number in the codename is the index number. However, this is not always true.

I have in the project window "Sheet8 (test)" and in the property windows "(Name) Sheet8".

In the Watches window, these are what I got:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(8).Index : 8 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(8).CodeName :  "Sheet16"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").Name : <Subscript out of range>
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(8).Name : this gives the name of Sheet16
```

Obviously, sheet index 8 refers to sheet16. Is there anyway, VBA or others, to make these two numbers in agreement? I mean I want sheets(8) to refer to Sheet8, not Sheet16.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  Either use the tab names, or give the sheet a meaningful codeName so you can refer to (eg) `AnnualSummary.Name` in your VBA.  There's really no need for the tab and code names to be in sync.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646333/renaming-a-sheet-code-name-through-vba-code-not-through-properties

Comment: Well, I usually do this: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(8).Range..... and I expect Sheets(8) to refer to Sheet8. I guess I need to change my habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the index reflex the tab number of the worksheet. So if you move the first sheet to position 3 it will have the index 3.
You cannot change the code name in run-time. You have to do it at the design phase.
I think there is no real solution for your problem. The only thing, you might do is rearranging the worksheets, but it is usually not a good option for the users. If you build a code on that, you have to ensure that the user cannot change the positions of the worksheets.