# How can I build a code that references another cell as a formula but can be overridden by manual inputs

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

So, i'm trying to build code where cells in AE can be overidden by manual input but references different ranges based on the given conditions. I've been at at for hours but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

The error I get is:
Method range of formula object failed

highlighthing this line of code

**  .Range("AE" & i).Formula = BMformula & i
**

```
Public Sub BedoverrideND(Bathmat As Worksheet, DSMaster As Worksheet, DSMformula As String, BMformula As String)
Dim i As Long

For i = 7 To getcostcoderange
    Select Case i
    Case 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
'        Do nothing
    Case Else
        If Bathmat.Range("B" & i).Value = 0 Or Bathmat.Range("B" & i).Value = "" Or _
            Not WorksheetFunction.IsFormula(Bathmat.Range("AE" & i)) _
            And Not IsEmpty(Bathmat.Range("AE" & i)) Then
        Else

            With Bathmat

                If Not WorksheetFunction.IsFormula(.Range("E" & i)) And Not IsEmpty(.Range("E" & i)) Then
                    .Range("AE" & i).Formula = BMformula & i
                ElseIf DSMaster.Range("T" & i).Value + DSMaster.Range("U" & i).Value <> 0 Then
                    .Range("AE" & i).Formula = DSMformula & i
                Else
                    .Range("AE" & i).Formula = BMformula & i
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End Select
Next i
End Sub
```

These are the codes that triggers the sub:

```
Public Sub BedOverrideSun()
    BedoverrideND shBathMatSun, shDSMasterSun, "='DS Master Sun'!V", "='Bath Mat Sun'!E"
End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E, AE:AE, BE:BE")) Is Nothing Then
 Call BedOverrideSun
```

I played around with it and managed to find the solution i was looking for:

```
    With Bathmat

        If Not WorksheetFunction.IsFormula(.Range("E" & i)) And Not IsEmpty(.Range("E" & i)) Or _
            DSMaster.Range("T" & i).Value + DSMaster.Range("U" & i).Value = 0 Then
                If .Range("AE" & i).Formula <> BMFormula & i Then
                    .Range("AE" & i).Formula = BMFormula & i
                End If
        ElseIf DSMaster.Range("T" & i).Value + DSMaster.Range("U" & i).Value <> 0 Then
            If .Range("AE" & i).Formula <> DSMaster & i Then
                .Range("AE" & i).Formula = DSMaster & i
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: I would check the value of i and getcostcoderange when error occurred.

Comment: Have you assigned a worksheet object to `shBathMatSun`?

Comment: I figured this could also be an issue at first @taller_ExcelHome but wouldn't the error occur first at `Bathmat.Range("B" & i).Value` then?

Comment: @vbakim I have checked them and the values are correct, however, the error seem to occur on the first target in the loop.  I tried modifying the code to a single cell to rule out the problem within the loop and the error still occurs in the same line of code.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome, i'm fairly new to vba. Do you mean using Dim and set within the the worksheet shBathMatSun itself? I did not have that but I tried that just now but the error still occurs. To clarify, is this what you mean?: Dim Bathmat As Worksheet
Dim DSMaster As Worksheet
Set Bathmat = shBathMatSun
Set DSMaster = shDSMasterSun

Comment: `Dim` declares variables and allocates storage space. `Set` assigns an object reference to a variable. eg. `Set shBathMatSun=Sheets("MySheet")`. I suggest that you include all the code in the original post.

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome, shBathMatSun is the codename of the sheet; just to clarify, do I still need to Dim even if I use the codenames?

Comment: I found that adding criterias like "IF .Range(rng).value = "" " or "<> "" " seem to prevent the errors, problem is i want values to be overwritten depending on criteria. So I don't think the problem lies in dim and set; I could be wrong.

Comment: I suspect there are lines of code that are causing an infinite loop, would that be possible?

Comment: I managed to find a solution, I have edited the question and placed the solution at the end.

Comment: I thought you couldn't change codenames of sheets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481428/19353309) to explain more about the differences and what @taller_ExcelHome was talking about. But apparently [you can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29646723/19353309) and I guess that confused us. As for your solution, please post it as an answer so people can know this is resolved.

Comment: @Notus_Panda; that was my mistake; it was supposed to be DSMformula and not DSMaster (pertaining to the last lines of code in the with statement)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the with portion of the code to this and it worked as expected.

```
 With Bathmat

        If Not WorksheetFunction.IsFormula(.Range("E" & i)) And Not IsEmpty(.Range("E" & i)) Or _
            DSMaster.Range("T" & i).Value + DSMaster.Range("U" & i).Value = 0 Then
                If .Range("AE" & i).Formula <> BMFormula & i Then
                    .Range("AE" & i).Formula = BMFormula & i
                End If
        ElseIf DSMaster.Range("T" & i).Value + DSMaster.Range("U" & i).Value <> 0 Then
            If .Range("AE" & i).Formula <> DSMFormula & i Then
                .Range("AE" & i).Formula = DSMFormula & i
            End If
        End If
    End With
```